# Typescript Interface in Interface

Tags: typescript, react-redux

I need your help with interface which is wrapped in second interface. I have the reducer like this:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export interface IStep {
  id: number;
  label: string;
  value: string;
  placeholder: string;
}

export interface InitialState {
  activeStep: number;
  steps: IStep[];
}

const initialState: InitialState = {
  activeStep: 0,
  steps: [
    {
      id: 0,
      label: 'First Name',
      value: '',
      placeholder: 'First Name',
    },
   ......
  ],
};

export const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'multiStepForm',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
   ......
  },
});
```

And I would like to use interface InitialState in my component called Step, that looks like below now.

```
import React from 'react';
import { IStep } from 'redux/reducers/multiStepForm';

interface IPropsStep {
  activeStep: number;
  steps: IStep[];
  handleChange: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
}

const Step = ({ activeStep, steps, handleChange }: IPropsStep): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <input
      id={steps[activeStep].id}
      type="text"
      onChange={handleChange}
      placeholder={steps[activeStep].placeholder}
      value={steps[activeStep].value}
    />
  );
};

export default Step;
```

It's easy to see that activeStep and steps are belong to InitialState, but I don't know how could I implement them.

I have been trying to do it in this way:

```
interface IPropsStep extends InitialState {
  handleChange: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
}

const Step = ({ handleChange }: IPropsStep): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <input
      id={steps[activeStep].id}
      type="text"
      onChange={handleChange}
      placeholder={steps[activeStep].placeholder}
      value={steps[activeStep].value}
    />
  );
};
```

But I have the errors because steps and activeStep is unknown here.
How can I hendle the issue?

Comment: Now that I think about it, your code should work just fine as your `InitialState` interface only has a `steps` and `activeStep` key. I personally prefer to do it as noted in my answer because that way you can't accidentally reference props that are not required by your component. But there shouldn't be errors though. What exactly is the error you get here?

Comment: @Luze "TypeScript error - Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string' | undefined" and the id is highlighted.

Comment: My guess is that there isn't an issue with your interface here, but I guess that the id of the steps in your `steps` prop that's passed down to your component doesn't have the correct type. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you should be able to access the keys from an `interface` like you would with an `object`.

```js
interface IPropsStep {
  activeStep: InitialState['activeStep'];
  steps: InitialState['steps'];
  handleChange: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
}
```

That way you directly refer to the `InitialState` interface.